# Google OAuth2.0 .NET Core failed to authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth), the code I use in my test controller is

```
[HttpGet("listdrive")]
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
public async Task<IActionResult> DriveFileList([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("hello drive");
    var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();

    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });

    var files = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
    var fileNames = files.Files.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    _logger.LogInformation(fileNames.Count.ToString());

    return Ok();
}
```

I have also configured my services and done the dependency injection, the client id and secret should work because I have tested them in Desktop application locally

```
services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
            // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
            // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
            // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "aaa";
            options.ClientSecret = "bbb";
        });
```

When I call the endpoint `listdrive`, this is the stack trace I get

```
[INFORMATION] 2024-02-06T00:07:16.5650763-04:00 [0HN16P1V10T97:00000003] - Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
2024-02-06T04:07:16.565674114Z DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2024-02-06T04:07:16.565679663Z Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3.GoogleScopedRequirement
[ERROR] 2024-02-06T00:07:56.4350328-04:00 [0HN16P1V10T86:00000002] - Connection id "0HN16P1V10T86", Request id "0HN16P1V10T86:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436839985Z  ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436844239Z  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436860190Z  ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436863714Z  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436866736Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436869650Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436875868Z    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436890225Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436904982Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436908002Z    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436917553Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436946952Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436954263Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<HandleAsync>g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436963512Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-02-06T04:07:56.436973409Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have add below code in your project.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    ...

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    ...
}
```

It seems that you are missing some configurations. If not, please check the versions of all packages to make sure they are compatible with your project. For example, use `.net core 3.1` version of packages.

Because by default, the latest version will be installed, please manually downgrade to a 3.1 compatible version.

If the problem persists, [please refer to this repo to see if the problem occurs](https://github.com/doggy8088/GoogleOAuthDriveApiV3Demo/tree/569000ba6fb813cf36fc957465ae85527224d7e1).